# Xcode 10, iOS: Test build failed even when all Tests have passed

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode10

All my unit tests have passed but the test build has failed. In the logs I am getting.

```
MyApp.app (35810) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. Underlying error: Test session exited(1) without checking in.)
```

On checking the following link I learnt that the above error is just a generic one and the actual log file will have a better description of the error.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6968#issuecomment-284421316

In the log file I get:-

```
/Users/swasidhant.chowdhury/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB36B628-072F-483A-A285-F3BC6E56EEC6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DEE2984D-B18B-4331-A298-E04423EF297C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftXCTest.dylib" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/swasidhant.chowdhury/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppWS-hdqtqxlvnzxcrhfksajhjcsdpwww/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/MyAppTests, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Users/swasidhant.chowdhury/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppWS-hdqtqxlvnzxcrhfksajhjcsdpwww/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/MyAppTests, 265): Symbol not found: __T0So8NSObjectCs7CVarArg10ObjectiveCWP
  Referenced from: /Users/swasidhant.chowdhury/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB36B628-072F-483A-A285-F3BC6E56EEC6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DEE2984D-B18B-4331-A298-E04423EF297C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftXCTest.dylib
```

I am not able to find anything on '__T0So8NSObjectCs7CVarArg10ObjectiveCWP' Any build setting I have to change to make this work ? Any linking I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the Derived Data folder? This just solved the issue for me. It seems `libswiftXCTest.dylib` should not be in your application's bundle if you compile the app in Xcode 10.